# Make ajax loaded content refreshing itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a div on a main page that loads content via ajax from another file (content.php), which refreshes automatically every 5 seconds.

```
function autoRefresh_div() {
  $("#div1").load("content.php", function() {
  setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 5000);
  });
}
```

In the content.php I have buttons and a function that executes a XMLHttpRequest that changes values in a database after a button is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function buttonClick(button_id) {
var valueA = document.getElementById('valueA'+id).value;
var valueB = document.getElementById('valueB'+id).value;
var url = "updatedb.php?valueA=" + valueA +"&valueB="+ B;

ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

if(ajax!=null){
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.send(null);
}
else{
    alert("Ajax Error");
}

}
</script>
```

After that values have been changes, I want that the main page reloads the div. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever calling `autoRefresh_div()` the first time in order for it to start cycling

Try

```
$(function(){
  autoRefresh_div();
});
```

Comment: In the actual script I do, I just forgot it when posting here.

Comment: Then I don't understand problem